# How to get a list of documents with a single billing read using Dart/Flutter? I.e., no listDocuments()?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

"Understand Cloud Firestore Billing" says "For queries other than document reads, such as a request for a list of collection IDs, you are billed for one document read." From what I can find, this isn't possible Using Dart/Flutter?

E.g., I see a lot of code like below, but this reads all the docs, so would be billed for N reads.

```
Future<List<String>> getSomeCollectionIDs() async {
  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await _someCollectionRef.getDocuments();
  List<DocumentSnapshot> docSnapshots = snapshot.documents;
  List<String> ids = docSnapshots.map((doc) => doc.documentID).toList();
  return ids;
}
```

Node.js has [listDocuments](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#listDocuments), but this isn't available with Dart?

If not, is there a way to accomplish a single-read list with a server function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API on any platform that can query for multiple documents costing only a single read.  Even `listDocuments` on the backend costs 1 read per document.  This is the cost of having a massively scalable database sharded over many computing resources.

Comment: Thanks Doug! I didn't know that about `listDocuments`. Why does the Firestore docs I quoted in my OP describe a perk that is impossible to achieve?

Comment: I don't see where it's documented that listDocuments only costs 1 read.

Comment: Ah. I misread it. The link is here (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#other-queries) but it says one read for a list of COLLECTION IDs, not document IDs, which is how I read it.

Comment: Yeah, listing collections is a different thing than listing documents.